# How to do cross-validation with multiple input data in CNN model with Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, cross-validation

My dataset consists of time series(10080) and other descriptive statistics features(85) **joint into one row**. DataFrame is `921 x 10166`.

The data looks something like this, with last 2 columns as `Y`(labels).

```
id    x0  x1    x2   x3   x4   x5  ... x10079   mean var ... Y0     Y1
1    40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  33       24   1       1      0
2    35  35.75 36.5 26.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29       31   2       0      1 
3    35  35.70 36.5 36.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29       25   1       1      0 
4    40  31.50 23.5 24.5 26.5 25   ...  33       29   3       0      1
 ... 
921  40  31.05 25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  23       33   2       0      1
```

I checked a few [blogs](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1711) and [tutorials](https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras/) which are helpful but I am not sure about how to deal with my input data which I had divided into `inputs_1` and `inputs_2` as shown in the model below:

```
inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(10081,1))

layer1 = Conv1D(64,14)(inputs_1)
layer2 = layers.MaxPool1D(5)(layer1)
layer3 = Conv1D(64, 14)(layer2)
layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(layer3)

inputs_2 = keras.Input(shape=(85,))            
layer5 = layers.concatenate([layer4, inputs_2])
layer6 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(layer5)
layer7 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(layer6)

model_2 = keras.models.Model(inputs = [inputs_1, inputs_2], output = [layer7])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.iloc[:,0:10166], merge[['Result_cat','Result_cat1']].values, test_size=0.2) 
X_train = X_train.to_numpy()
X_train = X_train.reshape([X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1]) 
X_train_1 = X_train[:,0:10081,:]
X_train_2 = X_train[:,10081:10166,:].reshape(736,85)  

X_test = X_test.to_numpy()
X_test = X_test.reshape([X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1]) 
X_test_1 = X_test[:,0:10081,:]
X_test_2 = X_test[:,10081:10166,:].reshape(185,85)    

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0005)
model_2.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = adam, metrics = ['acc'])
history = model_2.fit([X_train_1,X_train_2], y_train, epochs = 120, batch_size = 256, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20)])
```

The reason of dividing the features into 2 parts is that `inputs_1` is mainly about the time series data, while `inputs_2` is the descriptive statistics data. I thought it'd be better to separate them given the different nature of data. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

My question is, since my features data is divided and treated separately in the original model, should I do the same in cross validation(treat `inputs_1` and `inputs_2` separately)? In particular, for example, in Jason's model:

```
# MLP for Pima Indians Dataset with 10-fold cross validation
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# define 10-fold cross validation test harness
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
  # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Fit the model
    model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
    # evaluate the model
    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores), numpy.std(cvscores)))
```

evaluation was done using code `scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)` where `X[test], Y[test]` were used. In my case, since I have `inputs_1` and `inputs_2` instead of `X`(in example model), should I use something like `[inputs_1,inputs_2][test]`?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

---

**Update:**

I tried to concatenate `inputs_1` and `inputs_2` with

```
con_x = np.concatenate((X_train_1,X_train_2), axis = 1)
```

and changed the first line of model to

```
for train, test in kfold.split(con_x, Y):
```

but it returned

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d53a7058d157> in <module>()
     55 cvscores = []
---> 56 for train, test in kfold.split(con_x, Y):
     57 
     58     inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(10080,1))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    537         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    538             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
--> 539                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

But still, I am not sure if it is valid to concatenate `inputs_1` and `inputs_2` like this.